# Apachi httpd hangs on linux servers

Tags: php, python, linux, apache, mod-wsgi

In the last few months we're experiencing a major issue in our production php servers:

The httpd running on our linux servers hangs and not responding to new requests (up to request timeout) until we manually restart it.

We've documented this issue quite a bit, and I can point out a few major investigation directions we want to follow, but before starting the research i wanted to ask the community if someone else might be experiencing a similar problem.

we are running 4 instances of linux servers, with version:
**linux- 2.6.32-71, red had 4.4.4-13**

and httpd versions: 2.2.15

the php versions we are running are 5.5.15 and 5.5.10 (2 servers on each version).

we have detected a few suspicious errors in the logs, but notably couldnt find a specific error near the crashes :

1. Servers seems busy, (you may need to increase StartServers, or Min/MaxSpareServers) spawning X children, there are Y idle and Z total children
2. mod_wsgi Initializing Python
3. mod_wsgi Terminating Python
4. mod_wsgi Cleanup interpeter: ''
5. mod_wsgi: Destroying interpeters
6. KeyError(NUMBER) in  ignored

   **this is a php server, why is it throwing python errors?**
7. SIGHUP received. Attempting to restart - *** glibc detected *** /usr/bin/httpd: corrupted double-linked list: ADDRESS ***
8. Connection reset by peer: core_output_filter: writing data to network

   - We noticed that "/var/log/httpd/error_log" and "/var/log/httpd/access_log" removed every time the error occur.
     We are having a really hard time with this subject, and would really appriciate it if someone can help shed some light on this matter.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a PHP server I have to ask you why you have mod_wsgi enabled.

Look:

> WSGI is a specification of a generic API for mapping between an underlying web server and a Python web application. WSGI itself is described by Python PEP 3333:

From: http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/quick-configuration-guide.html

Try to disable this module and see what happens.

Comment: In the last 6 years we have mod_wsgi enabled, the truth is I have no idea why, it's legacy. we have no use of python in our proejct, we will disable this module, but why suddenly the httpd not responding to requests?

Comment: Well, this is really awkward. But, just now I've payed attention to this:

> "We noticed that "/var/log/httpd/error_log" and "/var/log/httpd/access_log" removed every time the error occur."

You mean the files are deleted from disc? Have you checked for rootkits?